# How can I transfer id from comp1 to comp2 when comp2 loads after a button click on comp1?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, salesforce-id, lightning-events, lightning-components

Comp1 and comp2 are 2 lightning component and are not in any relationship of parent-child. I used application in comp1 to fire and it is handled in comp2.

> Event

```
<aura:event type="APPLICATION" description="Event template" >
    <aura:attribute name='Id' type='String' access ='GLOBAL' />
</aura:event>
```

> Comp1

```
<aura:registerEvent name="PlanningAcctEvent" type="c:PlanningAcctEvent"/>
```

> Comp1.js

```
var evt = $A.get("e.c:PlanningAcctEvent");
    evt.setParams({ "Id": acctId});
    evt.fire();
```

> comp2

```
<aura:attribute name="acctId" type="String" />
<aura:handler event="c:PlanningAcctEvent" action="{!c.getIDFromPlanningAcctEvent}" />
```

> comp2.js

```
var ShowResultValue = event.getParam('Id');
    component.set('v.acctId',ShowResultValue);
```

Comp2 opens when a button is clicked in comp1 using *lightning:isUrlAddressable*. The problem here is that when the button is clicked and comp2 opens on screen it is not handling the event means I am not able to receive the id which I send through the application event.

I want the id in the comp2, please suggest what can be a possible solution here.

PS: Both components are independent.

Comment: I would probably re-do these components as lwc components and then use the messaging service.

Comment: I have to use aura components here. LWC is a better choice but can't use it at the moment.